# wooocmmerce template plugin

Tags: templates, woocommerce

I need to create a page and a shortcode inside it using this shortcode i will display different type of product on this template. but the problem is this that i am unable to call this page template properly using a plugin i have used mine `custom_locate_template()` function but i end with multiple time calling this page . Custom page template is called but issue is it is called twice and i don't understand why this page template include review section as i don't have review section code. any help will be appreciated

Comment: You want a particular post type to be shown in a page ? or multiple post types ?

Comment: i just want products of a particular term that i have created like for eg rental. this part is working fine i am able to get rental products but the issue is there are some anonymous code i am getting in the page template

Comment: can you describe more about the code ? which is appearing ?

Comment: hello Alice, thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

`$term = get_term_by( 'slug', 'custom_product_type','product_type');`

```
 $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
                'terms' => $term->term_id,
                'operator' => 'IN',
            )
        )
    ); 

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    echo "<div class='custom_product_type'>";

      if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php

            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
        ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

            <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                <?php $evt_mngr->wk_get_template( 'custom_product_type.php' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
        ?>

    <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

        // not found code ?>

    <?php endif;  

    echo "</div>";

    /**
     * woocommerce_after_main_content hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>
```

Comment: and i have used a shortcode inside this page created

Comment: turn off the `do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );` , check whether this review sections goes or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply alice,

Comment: but review section is still there event after i removed this code anything else i can over it

Comment: Look for the do_action hooks, actually it is doing that. I was trying to point that. Check which hook is responsible for it. Toggle each one by one.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems that in custom_product_type.php you have listed all your posts from same post type or tag. If so then you don't need the outer loop.

The following line --

```
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

Making it recursive. Suppose you have 2 posts (products), custom_product_type.php is called twice. If you have 3 posts it will call the template thrice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that either doesn't works for me if remove this code then no products are visible means inner code doesn't works

Comment: Just think a second  i have created a page and added a shortcode inside it and then in shortcode call back i have called a temlate file eg custom_produt_type.php then inside which i have used proper code to list product so i want to know how this code include review section and executing twice or thrice based on product

Comment: The code which you have posted here is already having a loop, and you have called custom_product_type.php inside that loop.

Comment: thanks for your reply again but that file just consist simple hooks  which display product details even if i removed all of code inside that file review section is already there

Comment: That means you are using all these code inside your shortcode function. One more question, is it reviews tab coming ?

Comment: let me explain again i have just included a file on shortcode callback like

Comment: <code>add_shortcode('new_post_type','callbackback_function');   function callbackback_function(){ // included a file  } </code>

Comment: so nside call back i have included a file like post_type.php which consist thsi code here

Answer (score 0):

To remove product reviews use following code in your theme's functions.php or any other relevant place.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woocommerce_product_reviews_tab', 30);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_tab_panels', 'woocommerce_product_reviews_panel', 30);
```

Comment: Hello again ,  i guess these hooks are used to remove tabs on backend not front end and doesn't work either i am saying that review section is on front end template

Comment: woocommerce_product_tabs is used in front-end

Comment: thanks for your reply alice ,  no then it doesn't work bad luck mine